# Share .obj files between different configurations

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My goal is to integrate testing into my development environment (as post-build step). I don't want to interfere with the DLLs that are generated in debug and release, so i plan to create new configurations for the project. But i don't want to compile every source file i have twice - once for the DLL, once for the test unit - I want to share the generated object files. How can I achieve this ?

I am developping in c++ using Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile the objs into a new lib project that is shared between the dll and your test project.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has an "intermediate" directory per configuration.  If the .obj files in there are newer than the source files it compiles, it won't regenerate them.

Comment: That could help. But I want to make sure that object files are compiled with the same options no matter which configuration i build first.

Comment: If you suspect the options may differ, there's no use _not_ rebuilding them.  Otherwise you need to compare the compile options for each 'item' in the project.